# How to set the classpath correctly in java

Tags: java, gson, classpath

I need to compile and run simple code using the `gson` library, but I can't use Maven, Gradle or the IDE.
The directory contains `Main.java` and `gson-2.9.0.jar`

`javac -cp gson-2.9.0.jar Main.java` works correctly and creates Main.class

But when I run `java -cp ./*: Main`, I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

I also tried the following commands:

```
java -cp gson-2.9.0.jar Main

java -cp gson-2.9.0.jar: Main

java -cp ./gson-2.9.0.jar:./* Main
```

But all these commands give the same result. I've never had to run code from the command line without Maven or IDEA before, so I think it's the classpath specification that's the problem. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main class is in a package (has a `package ...` declaration), you need to include the package name in the `java` call, e.g. `java -cp ... mypackage.Main`.

Additionally, the [`java` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) says about `-cp` / `--class-path`:

> As a special convenience, a class path element that contains a base name of an asterisk (*) is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR.

Therefore, using `*` for `.class` files does not work; instead you have to specify the directory name. Based on your question it looks like you are using Linux, and that the `.class` file and the JAR are in the same directory, so the following should work in your case:

```
java -cp gson-2.9.0.jar:. Main
```

(note the `.` after the `:`, indicating to include the current directory for the classpath)